# Application Insights Status Monitor doesn't track Sql dependencies for .Net Frameworks 4.5

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-cloud-services

I have a cloud service hosted application contains Web and Worker roles. To attach AppInsights telemetry I followed this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/cloudservices) including Sql Statements telemetry step. I've also relied on this sample (https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/tree/master/Samples/AzureEmailService)

After solution deployed I have all (http and azure storage) dependencies tracked, but sql.

Enviroment: .Net Framework v4.5, EntityFramework 6.1.3, Azure SDK 2.9.6

Nuget dependecies:

```
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.10.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.10.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.JavaScript" version="1.0.0-build00159" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.10.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener" version="2.10.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="2.10.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.10.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.10.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

I've checked logs and can see that AppInsights Status Monitor has been installed successully.

Any ideas?

**UPD**

Found SDK version:  rddf:2.10.0-32157

Any ideas how can I fix it to rddp?

Comment: can you double check if the Env variables are set? <Environment>
    <Variable name="COR_ENABLE_PROFILING" value="1" />
    <Variable name="COR_PROFILER" value="{324F817A-7420-4E6D-B3C1-143FBED6D855}" />
    <Variable name="MicrosoftInstrumentationEngine_Host" value="{CA487940-57D2-10BF-11B2-A3AD5A13CBC0}" />
  </Environment>

Comment: Other things to try - Restart IIS.

Comment: Also - if your SQL dependencies NOT collected at all? To collect SQL dependency you don't need to install status monitor. To get the full SQL query text only status monitor is required.

Comment: @cijothomas as mentioned in original article Env variables are required for Worker Roles. When i'm on .Net Framework 4.5 sql dependencies are not collected at all. I could collect them by changing osFamily="5", but still no SQL Command Text

Comment: can you collect some traces during application startup and during a time when sql calls are being make. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-troubleshoot-no-data#PerfView

Answer (score 1):

I'm Alex from Microsoft. My team works on cloud services extension. It appears we have a problem with installing Status Monitor for you to enable SQL tracking. My apologies.

Would that be possible for you to install Status Monitor by yourself as work-around on your Web and Worker roles as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/status-monitor-v2-api-enable-instrumentation-engine
?